# How to create a common cross-project reusable angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, import

Assuming the following project structure:

repo

- Project A

  - package.json

    - @angular/core
  - dashboard.component.ts
- Project B

  - package.json

    - @angular/core
  - panel.component.ts
- Common folder

  - package.json

    - @angular/core
  - button.component.ts

Each directory are their own little project, which include their own dependency.

I am currently trying to import the button component in Project A and Project B, using the regular module import. That being said, my import does go back a few steps `../../../common/button.component`

In order to declare a button in the common folder, i need to have a node_modules folder there containing @angular/core, otherwise I cannot use `import {Component} from '@angular/core'`

Now all that setup does look good and functional, but upon starting one of my application using `ng serve`, i get the following issue :

> ERROR in ../common/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
>   node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.

If I remove the `@angular/core` from the common module, and try to run again, I get :

> ERROR in ../common/components/angular/common.modules.ts(1,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common'.

Which does make sense, because the node_modules are no longer part of the common project.

I would like to know how to get around that issue.
I could probably import @angular/core from ProjectA or ProjectB, but then that would break the rule of not having any dependency over ProjectA and B for the common folder (But it's okay to have dependency over the common project).

Comment: Did you find a solution? Running into the same issue.. placing `@angular/common` in peerDependencies does not work either